# Research in spin geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, noncommutative-geometry, spin-geometry

I am currently learning differential geometry, but I have heard about the field of spin geometry and have skimmed through the book *Dirac Operators in Riemannian Geometry* by Thomas Friedrich. I have several questions regarding current research in the field of spin geometry:

- What are some open problems in the field?
- What are some current research directions?
- How does spin geometry connect with noncommutative geometry?

Comment: This is a pretty open-ended question. I think you might get more of a response if you asked something more concrete, perhaps something like: "What are the best recent survey papers in spin geometry?"

I would also suggest going to faculty websites and reading research statements - those will help give a lay of the land regarding research programs and open questions.

Comment: In noncommutative geometry, Dirac operators replace the notion of metric. See pp. 20-21 in http://www.its.caltech.edu/~matilde/IntroNCGCaltech2.pdf

Comment: As discovered by Lichnerowicz and developed by Gromov & Lawson, spin geometry is a notable pocket in the study of Riemannian metrics of positive scalar curvature. It seems that Schoen and Yau's minimal hypersurface techniques may be more powerful, but I am not an expert.

Comment: @QuartoBendir I will look into metrics with positive scalar curvature.

Comment: You could also take a look at the book ''Spin Geometry'' by Lawson and Michelsohn if you haven't already.  Also I think ''Riemannian Geometry'' by Peter Petersen might say a bit about current directions in spin geometry.

Comment: @HollisWilliams I am familiar with the book, I have not read it though. Thanks for the comment!